# Titanium webview crashes when adding a row to html table

Tags: webview, titanium

I have webview with inline html as a part of my window. It contains an html table with around 10 rows. When I try to add 1 more row to the table the app crashes.

```
    webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
        scalesPageToFit:false,
        top:0,
        bottom:0
    });

    var html = '<html>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<table width="98%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td align="left" height="25" colspan="2" style="color:#ba2424; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Use RedAnar To:</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td width="10%" height="25"><img src="'+sc+'"></td>'+
    '<td width="90%" height="25" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Store Card Data</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td width="10%" height="25"><img src="'+eo+'"></td>'+
    '<td width="90%" height="25" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Explore Offers</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td width="10%" height="25"><img src="'+cl+'"></td>'+
    '<td width="90%" height="25" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Capture Loyalty</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td width="10%" height="25"><img src="'+tp+'"></td>'+
    '<td width="90%" height="25" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Track Points</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td width="10%" height="25"><img src="'+vb+'" valign="absmiddle"></td>'+
    '<td width="90%" height="25" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">View Balances</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td align="left" height="25" colspan="2" style="color:#ba2424; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Card Description</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td align="left" height="20" colspan="2" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:normal">'+description+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td align="left" height="25" colspan="2" style="color:#ba2424; font-size:14; font-weight:bold">Highlights</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td align="left" height="20" colspan="2" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:normal">'+highlights+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '</table>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';

    webView.html = html;
```

if i try inserting 1 more row after this the app will crash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for iPhone or Android?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested your code, and it worked (I have used your variables as text though, because I don't know what's in them).

I've added the following line at the end, and it worked too:

```
'</tr>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td align="left" height="20" colspan="2" style="color:#000; font-size:14; font-weight:normal">'+"highlights"+'</td>'+
'</tr>'+
```

What line do you add when it doesn't work? And what error does it give when it crashes?